# Verifying the attribute in DynamoDB without using scan?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How to verify an attribute whether it present in table or not without using scan in dynamodb?

In my usecase, From client side, The customer request with their Customer_id for knowing the values of the product. In server side, have to check whether the entered customer_id already present in DynamoDB table or not. If not, have to make a new entry.

How can I implement this case without using SCAN operation to the table?

Comment: Can you provide your table schema and how `customer_id` is a part of it?

Comment: customer_id is the hash key(i.e., Primary key). Along with attributes - customer_name, Customer_email, customer_phone, customer_address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me that you want to do a conditional `PutItem` on this table: put the item into the table if there is not another item with the same `customer_id`. This is easy enough to do because the `customer_id` is the hash key of the table. From the `PutItem` [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html):

> **Note**
>
> To prevent a new item from replacing an existing item, use a conditional put operation with *ComparisonOperator* set to `NULL` for the
>   primary key attribute, or attributes.

Here is a quick example I coded up using the Dynamo DB document API in the Java SDK and running against DynamoDB Local:

```java
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Expected;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeDefinition;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ConditionalCheckFailedException;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.CreateTableRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeySchemaElement;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeyType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughput;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScalarAttributeType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.Tables;

public class StackOverflow {

    private static final String EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "example_table";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AmazonDynamoDB client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey"));
        client.setEndpoint("http://localhost:4000");
        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
        if (Tables.doesTableExist(client, "example_table")) client.deleteTable(EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);

        // Create table with hash key 'customer_id'
        CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest();
        createTableRequest.withTableName(EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
        createTableRequest.withKeySchema(new KeySchemaElement("customer_id", KeyType.HASH));
        createTableRequest.withAttributeDefinitions(new AttributeDefinition("customer_id", ScalarAttributeType.S));
        createTableRequest.withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(15l, 15l));
        dynamoDB.createTable(createTableRequest);
        Tables.waitForTableToBecomeActive(client, EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);

        Table exampleTable = dynamoDB.getTable(EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);

        exampleTable.putItem(new Item()
                .withPrimaryKey("customer_id", "ABCD")
                .withString("customer_name", "Jim")
                .withString("customer_email", "jim@gmail.com"));

        System.out.println("After Jim:");
        exampleTable.scan()
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();

        try {
            exampleTable.putItem(new Item()
                    .withPrimaryKey("customer_id", "EFGH")
                    .withString("customer_name", "Garret")
                    .withString("customer_email", "garret@gmail.com"), new Expected("customer_id").notExist());
        } catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException e) {
            System.out.println("Conditional check failed!");
        }

        System.out.println("After Garret:");
        exampleTable.scan()
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();

        try {
            exampleTable.putItem(new Item()
                    .withPrimaryKey("customer_id", "ABCD")
                    .withString("customer_name", "Bob")
                    .withString("customer_email", "bob@gmail.com"), new Expected("customer_id").notExist());
        } catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException e) {
            System.out.println("Conditional check failed!");
        }

        System.out.println("After Bob:");
        exampleTable.scan()
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
After Jim:
{ Item: {customer_email=jim@gmail.com, customer_name=Jim, customer_id=ABCD} }

After Garret:
{ Item: {customer_email=garret@gmail.com, customer_name=Garret, customer_id=EFGH} }
{ Item: {customer_email=jim@gmail.com, customer_name=Jim, customer_id=ABCD} }

Conditional check failed!
After Bob:
{ Item: {customer_email=garret@gmail.com, customer_name=Garret, customer_id=EFGH} }
{ Item: {customer_email=jim@gmail.com, customer_name=Jim, customer_id=ABCD} }
```