# Dynamodb batchgetItem API behavior for non existent keys

Tags: exception, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

What is the behavior of DynamoDb `BatchGetItem` API if none of the keys exist in dynamodb?
Does it returns an empty list or throws an exception?

I am not sure about this after reading their doc: [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) 
but I may be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

`BatchGetItem` will not throw an exception. The results for those items will not be present in the [`Responses`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html#DDB-BatchGetItem-response-Responses) map in the response. This is also stated in the `BatchGetItem` [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html):

> If a requested item does not exist, it is not returned in the result.
>   Requests for nonexistent items consume the minimum read capacity units
>   according to the type of read. For more information, see Capacity
>   Units Calculations in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide.

This behavior is also easy to verify. This is for a Table with a hash key attribute named `customer_id` (the full example I am using is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045814/verifying-the-attribute-in-dynamodb-without-using-scan/29056527#29056527)):

```
dynamoDB.batchGetItem(new BatchGetItemSpec()
        .withTableKeyAndAttributes(new TableKeysAndAttributes(EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME)
                .withHashOnlyKeys("customer_id", "ABCD", "EFGH")
                .withConsistentRead(true)))
        .getTableItems()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .forEach(System.out::println);

dynamoDB.batchGetItem(new BatchGetItemSpec()
        .withTableKeyAndAttributes(new TableKeysAndAttributes(EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME)
                .withHashOnlyKeys("customer_id", "TTTT", "XYZ")
                .withConsistentRead(true)))
        .getTableItems()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
example_table=[{ Item: {customer_email=jim@gmail.com, customer_name=Jim, customer_id=ABCD} }, { Item: {customer_email=garret@gmail.com, customer_name=Garret, customer_id=EFGH} }]
example_table=[]
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. 
From the document it looks like if there is any issue with reading a particular key on the server side, that particular key would be sent as part of separate list which clients can retry.

Comment: In this case, does dynamodb charge you for empty reads or not?
If I keep on querying for an item, which doesnot exist in the table, will it throttle/consume my read capacity?