# Amazon DynamoDB: Want to print out list of all tables and print out the primary keys associated with a table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I'm trying Amazon's tutorial on dynamoDB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.DDBLocal.html

As I'm working through it, I can't figure out how to do simple things like:
print the names of the tables I've created or figure out what the primary keys are in a particular table, t.

I'm assuming that there is probably some really easy way to do this, I just haven't seen it.

Answer (score 3):

DynamoDBLocal is essentially a DynamoDB instance running on your own computer with its own endpoint. The way to interact with it is the same way you would with the actual DynamoDB service.

The easiest way to do that is choose an API and make requests with the local endpoint. [See here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html#Tools.DynamoDBLocal.Using) for some basic examples of how to set the endpoint.

In your case, it sounds like you want to use a few different API operations, which the syntax will differ depending on which language/SDK you use:

1. [`ListTables`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html) - self-explanatory
2. [`Scan`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) - "The Scan operation returns one or more items and item attributes by accessing every item in a table or a secondary index".
3. [`DescribeTable`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html) - "Returns information about the table, including the current status of the table, when it was created, the primary key schema, and any indexes on the table."

I have a fairly full example of a few operations using the Java SDK in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045814/verifying-the-attribute-in-dynamodb-without-using-scan/29056527#29056527) if you want some reference.